# Index Error when using Arrays! Python

Tags: python

I'm having some trouble when trying to make a string that changes one character at a time, i'm not sure what the problem is!?

I get a index out of range error
`Using Trinket`

```
import random
geneSet = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!."
target = "Hello World!"

guess = []

for x in range (0,len(target)):
  guess.append(random.choice(geneSet))
  print len(guess)

print guess

while guess != target:
  index = random.randint(0,len(target))
  guess[index] = random.choice(geneSet)
  print guess
```

Comment: Note that if you say "array" in the context of Python, most people will think you're referring to the numpy library. Then there's an added complication of there actually being array objects in Python (though not well used). This is just a _list_.

Comment: Trust the Traceback, somehow you are trying to index a position that doesn't exist. The usual suspect would be the expression that creates or limits the index.

Answer (score 0):

inside while loop, it gives error when `random.randint(0, len(target))` returns 12.

so change that line into:

```
index = random.randint(0,len(target)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

> index = random.randint(0,len(target))

Should be

> index = random.randint(0,len(target)-1)

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint) says:

> random.randint(a, b)
>
> Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b.

It seems your problem is in the statement:

`index = random.randint(0,len(target))`

The position `len(target)` is invalid.

I think it should be

`index = random.randint(0,len(target)-1)`